# get a permanent browseNodeId from amazon product API

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-product-api

I'm using Amazon Product API to get new products of certain category everyday.
Sometimes the BrowseNodeId changes, let's say I want to get new books about 'Python', at the moment I'm calling Amazon API like this:

get_new_products(BrowseNodeId=36848)

but sometimes BrowseNodeId changes and I get this error:

> InvalidParameterValue: AWS.InvalidParameterValue: 36848 is not a
>   valid value for BrowseNodeId. Please change this value and retry your
>   request.

What can I do to keep the BrowseNodeId of Python updated? Which API should I use to get the BrowseNodeId passing the string 'Python'?

I need something like this getBrowseNodeId('Python') **to get the correct and updated** BrowseNodeId to avoid the error posted over.

Any advice or workflow that I can follow?

Thanks in advance.
Best regards.

Answer (score 0):

Amazon does seem to change the Ids every so often. The [recommended way](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSECommerceService/latest/DG/FindingBrowseNodes.html) is to take a product and go through its associated BrowseNodes.